# How to order Dates in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using C# and LINQ, I have some Date in type `Date`

At the moment I am using this script to order a list by date of start, from the earlier to the latest.

With the following code my events are not sorted:

```
      events.OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeStart).ToList();    
      return events.AsQueryable();
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Do remember that `AsQueryable()` and `ToList()` means vastly different things depending on the underlying datastructure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`events.OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeStart)`: Declare a query that sorts events by property *DateTimeStart*. The query is not performed yet.

`events.OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeStart).ToList();`: Process the previous query. Iterate through all *events*, checks their *DateTimeStart*, sort them and safe result as a *List* and then... discard the result! Because you didn't safe it. Compare it with something like that:

```
int a = 0;
a + 1;
b = a; // b is 0
```

`return events.AsQueryable();`: Here you are returning your original *events* instead of sorted.

You should write your code as follows:

```
return events.OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeStart).ToList().AsQueryable();
```

That version will create static list of sorted events. If now you change the *events* list, the result will not take into account your changes.

The second solution is:

```
return events.OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeStart).AsQueryable();
```

That version will do no work. It just declarates a manner to sort *events* and returns that manner as *IQueryable*. If you use returned value in future code it will always contain all sorted events even if you add new ones prior to use that.

Answer (score 12):

`events.OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeStart).ToList()` creates a new list, and you don't return it.

You probably want something like

```
return events.OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeStart).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks all for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

store your orderedevents in a variable and return this variable asQueryable();

```
var orderedEvents = events.OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeStart).ToList();    

return orderedEvents.AsQueryable();
```

or if you dont need that variable return your ordered events directly.

```
return events.OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeStart).ToList().AsQueryable();
```

Comment: worth mentioning that ToList() will evaluate the LINQ expression and store the result. After that, returning an IQueryable on top of that list is of no use.

Comment: yes you are right. i´m only providing his updated code. I don´t know the reason why he returns it asQueryable();

Comment: maybe what he wanted is something like: `return events.OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeStart).AsQueryable();`